# Is it possible to break a result column into two in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know whether it is possible or not in mysql, but any suggestion would be appreciated. Plus I am calling this query through my php script and using the results in google charts.

my query returns following result.

```
mysql> SELECT substring_index(xo.module_name, '/', 1) as Module, COUNT(date) AS Count, Year(date) as Year FROM xclude_run xr, join_run_object jro, xclude_object xo WHERE xr.syshost='darter' AND xo.module_name IS NOT NULL AND xr.run_id = jro.run_id AND jro.obj_id = xo.obj_id GROUP BY Module, Year  ORDER BY Module, Year desc;
+--------------------------+-------+------+
| Module                   | Count | Year |
+--------------------------+-------+------+
| alps                     |    98 | 2015 |
| atp                      |  1220 | 2015 |
| atp                      |   279 | 2014 |
| boost                    |    28 | 2015 |
| cce                      | 10086 | 2015 |
| cp2k                     |     6 | 2014 |
| cray-hdf5                |    16 | 2014 |
| cray-hdf5-parallel       |   114 | 2015 |
| cray-libsci              |   721 | 2015 |
| cray-libsci              |   514 | 2014 |
| cray-mpich               |  1771 | 2015 |
| cray-mpich               |   386 | 2014 |
| cray-netcdf-hdf5parallel |    50 | 2015 |
| cray-netcdf-hdf5parallel |    76 | 2014 |
| cray-shmem               |  1832 | 2015 |
| cray-tpsl                |    29 | 2015 |
| cray-trilinos            |   104 | 2015 |
| craype-intel-knc         |  2676 | 2015 |
| craype-intel-knc         |   171 | 2014 |
| dmapp                    |   920 | 2015 |
| dmapp                    |     8 | 2014 |
| fftw                     |   288 | 2015 |
| fftw                     |  1791 | 2014 |
| gcc                      |  5371 | 2015 |
| gcc                      |   180 | 2014 |
| intel                    |    14 | 2015 |
| pmi                      |  2480 | 2015 |
| pmi                      |   416 | 2014 |
| rca                      |   920 | 2015 |
| udreg                    |  2479 | 2015 |
| udreg                    |   416 | 2014 |
| ugni                     |  2479 | 2015 |
| ugni                     |   416 | 2014 |
| wlm_detect               |    49 | 2015 |
| xpmem                    |  2479 | 2015 |
| xpmem                    |   416 | 2014 |
+--------------------------+-------+------+
36 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I wanted the results to show in a neat way year on year basis, something like -

```
+--------------------------+-------+------+-------+-------+
| Module                   | Count | Year | Count | Year |
+--------------------------+-------+------+-------+-------+
| alps                     |    98 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| atp                      |  1220 | 2015 |   279 | 2014 |
| boost                    |    28 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| cce                      | 10086 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| cp2k                     |     0 | 2015 |     6 | 2014 |
| cray-hdf5                |     0 | 2015 |    16 | 2014 |
| cray-hdf5-parallel       |   114 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| cray-libsci              |   721 | 2015 |   514 | 2014 |
| cray-mpich               |  1771 | 2015 |   386 | 2014 |
| cray-netcdf-hdf5parallel |    50 | 2015 |    76 | 2014 |
| cray-shmem               |  1832 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| cray-tpsl                |    29 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| cray-trilinos            |   104 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| craype-intel-knc         |  2676 | 2015 |   171 | 2014 |
| dmapp                    |   920 | 2015 |     8 | 2014 |
| fftw                     |   288 | 2015 |  1791 | 2014 |
| gcc                      |  5371 | 2015 |   180 | 2014 |
| intel                    |    14 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| pmi                      |  2480 | 2015 |   416 | 2014 |
| rca                      |   920 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| udreg                    |  2479 | 2015 |   416 | 2014 |
| ugni                     |  2479 | 2015 |   416 | 2014 |
| wlm_detect               |    49 | 2015 |     0 | 2014 |
| xpmem                    |  2479 | 2015 |   416 | 2014 |
+--------------------------+-------+------+-------+------+
```

Is there any way to achieve this in mysql?
Thanks for your advice.

This is a recent implementation, so I am looking for data 2014 onwards.

Comment: how many pairs horizontally are you looking for year-over-year ? What if (year -1) exists but not for year. Devil's in the Details. Don't see it above.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of years, it can be done using joins on subqueries.

Comment: This is a recent implementation, so I am looking for data 2014 onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP is added in the tags, one simple way would be to build a query with joins, that loops over all the years:

```
// Your query for a particular year
function originalQuery($currYear) {
    return "(SELECT substring_index(xo.module_name, '/', 1) as Module, 
    COUNT(date) AS Count, Year(date) as Year FROM xclude_run xr, join_run_object 
    jro, xclude_object xo WHERE xr.syshost='darter' AND xo.module_name IS NOT NULL
    AND xr.run_id = jro.run_id AND jro.obj_id = xo.obj_id GROUP BY Module, Year  
    ORDER BY Module HAVING year = $currYear) as q$currYear ";
}

// The joined query can be generated using a for loop for multiple years.
$joinedQuery = "SELECT * " . 
    "FROM " . originalQuery(2015) . " JOIN " . originalQuery(2014) .
    "ON q2015.Module = q2014.Module" .
    "ORDER by q2015.Module";
```

Comment: Although, whole record is rejected if the count is zero in any year. I need to fix that for eg: alps, boots, cce all are omitted from the results

Comment: Change the type of join. Use a `LEFT JOIN` or something.